# Making a DRF POST operation work like a Django Admin create object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am sorry if this question exists elsewhere, but in my search, I did not find anything on StackOverflow or the internet answering my query.

I am new to Django Rest Framework. I am working with a MCQ Question Submission model, which records the submission of a quiz as a collection of answers of the examinee to various questions(stored as MCQ Answer model) of a MCQ Quiz( MCQ Quiz model and Choice model).

I want to POST the student's name, the quiz name and the Answer Model instances and want to automatically calculate the marks of the student before saving the serializer.

Currently, my position is this - If I go the Django Admin and manually create some Answer instances and a Submission instance combining them, then the marks get automatically calculated. But the same doesn't happen while submitting a POST request.

Could anyone tell that what is the difference between a POST and an instance creation from Admin?

What I do now is this.

In serializers.py

```
class  MCQSubmissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    marks = serializers.IntegerField(source='marks_obtained')
    emailId = serializers.EmailField(source='fetch_email')
    class Meta:
        model = MCQSubmission
        fields = '__all__'
```

In models.py

```
class MCQSubmission(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(MCQQuiz, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    submitted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def marks_obtained(self):
        marks = 0        
        for a in self.mcqanswer_set.all():
            marks += a.marks()
        return marks
    def fetch_email(self):
        return self.student.email
```

This creates a JSON object containing the marks and email-id when made from the Django Admin. But it asks to provide for marks, email-id when doing a post request.

I recently also found out that without a mcqanswer_Set object also given in the post, marks can anyways not be calculated.

**EDIT: My views.py**

```
class MCQSubmissionList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        submission = MCQSubmission.objects.all()
        serializer = MCQSubmissionSerializer(submission, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = MCQSubmissionSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            submission = serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

As you can see, I have not written anything special in either the get or post views. Similarly, I first make a get request which gives me some already created JSONs and I POST one of them by removing email and marks.

Comment: How `automatically calculate` in Django Admin work? Please show your model too, thanks

Comment: Could you also show your view and the json you are sending?

Comment: Were you able to replicate the issue?